# IS there reflection in Oracle Forms 6 or later?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

IS there reflection in Oracle Forms 6 or later?

Is it possible to enumarate labels or other elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forms is an old and venerable programming language, and it doesn't support full-on reflection, Java style.  However, it does have a complement of GET and SET functions which enable us to interrogate and manipulate a Form's metadata.

So we can step through the items of a block and get their labels using GET_ITEM_PROPERTY like this (example adapted from the documentation):

```
DECLARE 
  cur_itm   VARCHAR2(80); 
  cur_block VARCHAR2(80) := :System.Cursor_Block;
  cur_label VARCHAR2(120); 
BEGIN 
  cur_itm   := Get_Block_Property( cur_block, FIRST_ITEM ); 
  WHILE ( cur_itm IS NOT NULL ) LOOP 
    cur_itm := cur_block||’.’||cur_itm; 
    cur_label := Get_Item_Property( cur_itm, LABEL);
    -- do whatever you want with the label here 
    cur_itm := Get_Item_Property( cur_itm, NEXTITEM ); 
  END LOOP; 
END;
```

You could change the LABEL of the current item using SET_ITEM_PROPERTY.

Note: LABEL is a property which only applies to certain items (buttons, checkboxes, etc) so you might what to include a test for the item type and perhaps grab the PROMPT_TEXT instead, if that's appropriate.

There are loads of ways we can change the appearance and behaviour of a Form on the fly.  The Form Builder Reference covers all the built-ins, so there's no point in recapitulating it here.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/forms/forms/A73074_01.pdf).

Comment: as always an excellent answer, I wasn't sure if the term reflection in this context meant the OP was looking for something like the Forms JDAPI or it's C implementation older brother. Glad I held back from posting.